# Select changin at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

Here is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <script>
    function run() {
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function up() {
        //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
            var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        //}
        alert(dop);
    }
</script>
<script>
    function up() {
        var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        pop(dop); // Calling function pop
    }

    function pop(val) {
        alert(val);
    }?
</script>
<script type language="javascript">
function cargar_imagen(imagen) {
var img = document.getElementById("myimage");
var img_dir = "http://silvercowgames.com/ENADRYA/imagenes/cartas";
if (img) {
img.src = img_dir + imagen;
}
}
</script>
<select name="imagenes" onchange="run();cargar_imagen(this.value)" id="Ultra1">
<option value="">Imagen 1</option>
<option value="/Johas/Madriguera-Tolva.jpg" >Imagen 2</option>
<option value="/Johas/Coriacia-ancestral.jpg">Imagen 3</option>
<option value="4.png">Imagen 4</option>
</select>

 <select id="Ultra">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value="18">Imagen 1</option>
     <option value="16">Imagen 2</option>
     <option value="5">Imagen 3</option>
     <option value="4">Imagen 4</option>
</select><br><br>
<script>
document.getElementById('Ultra1').addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById('Ultra').selectedIndex = document.getElementById('Ultra1').selectedIndex;
}, false);
</script>

<img alt src="http://silvercowgames.com/ENADRYA/imagenes/cartas/Johas/Coriacia-ancestral.jpg" id="myimage" align="center">
<br>
<form name="frm1">
uno<input type="text" name="uno" id="srt")>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if you execute that you may see that when you change 1 select the other one changes too but if you change and the go back to the last option the number that is displayed in the txt box change and its not the same.

I need that the numbers match when you change the select option.

Please help me

Comment: Just wanted to do it [using JQuery for fun :)](http://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/bpap5L99/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <script>
    function run() {
        document.getElementById("srt").value = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
    }
</script>
<script>
    function up() {
        //if (document.getElementById("srt").value != "") {
            var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        //}
        alert(dop);
    }
</script>
<script>
    function up() {
        var dop = document.getElementById("srt").value;
        pop(dop); // Calling function pop
    }

    function pop(val) {
        alert(val);
    }?
</script>
<script type language="javascript">
function cargar_imagen(imagen) {
var img = document.getElementById("myimage");
var img_dir = "http://silvercowgames.com/ENADRYA/imagenes/cartas";
if (img) {
img.src = img_dir + imagen;
}
}
</script>
<select name="imagenes" onchange="" id="Ultra1">
<option value="">Imagen 1</option>
<option value="/Johas/Madriguera-Tolva.jpg" >Imagen 2</option>
<option value="/Johas/Coriacia-ancestral.jpg">Imagen 3</option>
<option value="4.png">Imagen 4</option>
</select>

 <select id="Ultra">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value="18">Imagen 1</option>
     <option value="16">Imagen 2</option>
     <option value="5">Imagen 3</option>
     <option value="4">Imagen 4</option>
</select><br><br>
<script>
document.getElementById('Ultra1').addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById('Ultra').selectedIndex = document.getElementById('Ultra1').selectedIndex;

    run();
    alert(document.getElementById('Ultra').value);
    cargar_imagen(document.getElementById('Ultra1').value)

}, false);
</script>

<img alt src="http://silvercowgames.com/ENADRYA/imagenes/cartas/Johas/Coriacia-ancestral.jpg" id="myimage" align="center">
<br>
<form name="frm1">
uno<input type="text" name="uno" id="srt")>
</form>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5n1xqzLc/)

Comment: nope dude , its doesnt work :(, you can see that the numbers are never the same if you touch imagen 1 then imagen 2 and then imagen 1, you will see that it still going crazy .S

Comment: But i think i can fix that

Comment: @NicoBruno Did you check the fiddle, I see the numbers correctly in textbox and in the alert

Comment: Now its working fine, i am getting confused by the alert XD, thank you very much really !